# .htaccess working on XAMPP localhost but not on Webhosting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, altorouter

Hei guys,
for my webpage I wanted to implement some simple REST-Services to serve some Json.

To achieve that I created subfolder api and in this folder I created index.php and .htaccess file.

index.php uses AltoRouter to handle Routes called on /api.

.htaccess locks like following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

mod_rewrite is enable on my webhoster. (I was abelt to test this using some simple examples served by the webhoster)

I tested everthing on my local computer using localhost xampp.
Everthing is working fine. (GET and POST Requests)

After uploading this to my webpage I figured out, that POST Requests are Redirected to GET and therefore are not working.

Can anybody help with that issue. I need this POST Requests to be redirected to my index.php and be handled there to make some data update on my webpage.

Regards
Manuel

There is an update:
My Webhoster seams to use a nginx proxy that redirects to Apache.
POST seams to get coverted to GET and therefore my mechanism is not working anymore.
Can anyone tell me how to force nginx to redirect POST as POST?

Manuel

Comment: Can we assume that instead of "POST Requests to be redirected to my index.php" you actually want them to get internally _rewritten_ ?

Comment: What do You mean by internally rewritten ? I want to handle all requests to <domain>/api/... with my index.php using the router class AltoRouter. Using the .htaccess was the recommended way to achieve this. And for localhost this just works fine

Comment: But yes, if thats the correct speach I don't want redirection I want rewrite

Answer (score 0):

You can include the PHP file in your /api folder in your PHP file in your Root folder.

Just add the line `include "./api/index.php"` to your PHP in the Root folder.
Then the functions work in the PHP file in the /api folder, without having to open that specific PHP file in the /api folder.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: unfortunately I got no php file in the root folder, add would this even help rewriting every path eg. ./api/test/test/test to the ./api/index.php ?